# How do you make payments to firebase / Google Cloud Platform (GCP) from India?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, payment

We have just move to production and are not able to add any payment method to the GCP.

1. Google rejects our credit, debit cards due to some [error](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/This-action-couldn-t-be-completed-Try-again-later-OR-BSBBF-103/td-p/179349) at their end. The support team says its a known issue but they have no timeline to resolve this.
   The cards are VISA and Mastercard, match all the requirements as [this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#supported_payment_methods) and have no problem on other platforms.
2. Their 1st suggestion is to enable invoice based billing but since we are newly founded startup we don't match their criteria of revenue.
3. The 2nd suggestion was to connect with google cloud partner to process the payment. I have contacted 10 Partners and everyone says they cant help us with payments.

This is a pressing issue for us as free credits will run out in a month. I want to know how others are dealing with this since its not very specific to us.

Comment: Possibly IAM related: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access ...Google Cloud India Private Limited seems to have their own terms: https://cloud.google.com/terms/india - I'd ask them.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have all the privileges, I have raised this with support around 5 times I think, there were not sharing additional info due to security reasons

Comment: When the cannot provide a solution in a timely manner, maybe consider an abstraction alike [Terraform](https://cloud.hashicorp.com/products/terraform), where the infrastructure provider is secondary; you'd still need to find one which accepts your card.

Comment: 1) ask your bank or credit card company why they are declining Google's authorization attempts. 2) prepay your Google Cloud account. 3) get a US bank-based Visa/Mastercard. Your bank can help you. 4) I do not use PayPal but I believe Google accepts PayPal.

Comment: @JohnHanley we contacted the bank and there are no issues at the banks end. For prepaying we need to add the card and this is not happening. The Card is Visa and meets the Google's payment criteria. I gotta reconfirm for paypal, I didnt quite see it as an option

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks, I was unaware of this. I'll check it out!

Comment: Go back to your credit card company. Ask them to look up the transaction and tell you the authorization code they sent to Google. Ask for the date/timestamp as well. Most of the problems are caused by a) the card does not verify your identity; b) the card does not accept recurring transactions; c) incorrect authorization details. A and B are caused by your credit card company. Go back and ask them to show you they authorized Google.

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley, Google clarified us it isn't the fault of the credit card company but issue at their end. But they fail to come up with any other solution than expecting us to wait till it resolves. But we cant keep a production app on ventilator like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to regulations from the Reserve Bank of India, you might be unable to charge automatically.

1. If your usage cost is more than 5000 INR; you cannot use it for automatic payments as per RBI guidelines.
2. For the time being you can use [manual payments](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment) for your usage and you can add an extra amount for future use.
3. Try with any local reseller who can accept more forms of payments or who can help you with [invoiced billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts#billing_account_types). You can find resellers on [Google partners](https://cloud.google.com/find-a-partner/) page.

From October 1st 2022 Google can no longer save your card details in the current format as per RBI guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, we were unable to do manual payments till some time back but last week we were able to.

Answer (score 1):

So till sometime back we were not able to process manual payments, but now we are able to.

As Abhijeet rightly pointed, you can follow this article https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment and pay in advance so that the production remains up.